# How to encode some entities and not others?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have an attribute that is a string.

A typical value would be `<p>foo — that's an em dash</p>`.

I need to convert this to `<p>foo &mdash; that's an em dash</p>`.

That is, I need the HTML tags untouched, but the unencoded entities encoded. Ideally, with output that is in `utf-8`.

This is to prevent repeated errors of this sort:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 - 0 failed attempts
```

I have tried various incarnations of `gsub`, `force_encoding` and `Nokogiri`, but without luck. Perhaps one of these was a step in the right direction but I did not do everything right?

What should I do?

Comment: which ruby version are you using? you might want to declare the ruby encoding of the source file.

Comment: I'm on 1.9.3. What did you mean by "you might want to declare the ruby encoding of the source file"?

Comment: please try a `# coding: UTF-8` in the very first line of your ruby file (its just a guess though)

Comment: I guess you mean the `review.rb` model file in which I get the error? I added `# coding: UTF-8` but it had no effect.